# build a mysqli query to fetch inner joins for two rows

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `bank` and `transaction`... a transaction is made between 2 banks which are stored in `transaction` table I have a row in transaction =>

```
id | from_bank_id | to_bank_id | transaction_amount
1  |  2           |   4        |     10000
```

now I want to get names of the banks with foreign keys 2 4 which are in `bank` table

```
id | bank_name
2  |  BOI
3  |  SBI
4  |  HDFC
```

How do I get this result in just one query

```
from_bank | to_bank | transaction_amount
BOI       | HDFC    |   1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.transaction_amount, b1.name, b2.name 
FROM transaction t 
JOIN bank b1 on t.from_bank_id = b1.id
JOIN bank b2 on t.to_bank_id = b2.id
```